# SQL Server, Sub-query from different object connection

Tags: sql-server, object, connection, subquery

I'm busy implementing a new ERP system, doing a data migration.
While were migrating data - the live environment keeps on evolving.
So we're still in the testing phase, homing in on all the scripts.
Now every new field / area that I start with, wants to update newly created records that weren't in the previous phase was done.

So we're sitting different environments:

- 10.0.0.1 - Old server
- 10.0.0.2 - Migration server

So in SQL - I've got two connections.

What I want to do, is select master data from the old server, that already has main accounts on the new server:

```
SELECT 
customer_code
FROM customer  --10.0.0.2 old server

 WHERE customer_code IN

 (
  USE datamigration  --10.0.0.1 new server
  SELECT cust_code FROM [dbo].[new_table]  --data on new server
 )
```

So, only show me records from old server that has master file on new server.

Thank you!

SYSTEM
Windows server 2012 
SQL server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) and use [four part naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SELECT 
customer_code
FROM customer
WHERE customer_code IN
(
  SELECT cust_code FROM [Linked server].[datamigration].[dbo].[new_table]
)
```

NB If `SELECT cust_code FROM [Linked server].[datamigration].[dbo].[new_table]` returns any `NULL` values your whole SQL statement will return nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  The 4 part naming is a good pointer, but I'll need to go do some homework on linking servers. This will be a first for me...

Comment: It's quite easy to configure. In Management Studio go Server Objects --> Linked Servers. Right click and New Linked Server. Follow your nose and you should be able to set it up quite easily.

Comment: Ok, ja - that was easy enough! Thanx, now I just need to get my access permissions right... Error 15007

Answer (score 0):

Just use linked server.
Once you have added your linked server you can refer it from other server.

Suppose to have your new server linked in old server with the name `[10.0.0.1]`

Now you can simply use (from old server)

```
SELECT customer_code
FROM customer  --10.0.0.2 old server
WHERE customer_code IN (  
  SELECT cust_code FROM [10.0.0.1].[NewDatabaseName].[dbo].[new_table]  --data on new server
)
```

I will use a join syntax

```
SELECT customer_code, cust_code
FROM customer  t_old --10.0.0.2 old server
join [10.0.0.1].[NewDatabaseName].[dbo].[new_table] t_new on customer_code = cust_code
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion on the join... Thank you! Will try it out.